# .htaccess language based RewriteRule like example.com/en/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write redirect directives in the .htaccess to forward internally all user requests like this:

- Every request in a language folder should redirect to the requested file with the language query string:

```
example.com/en/contact.php -> example.com/contact.php?lang=en
```

- Redirect any request without language path to a default language folder like this:

```
example.com -> example.com/en
```

- Remove trailing slash if the address is entered with it:

```
example.com/en/ to example.com/en
```

- For the folder projects, every request should lead to the view-project.php file with the respective query strings:

```
example.com/en/projects/test -> example.com/view-project.php?lang=en&path=test
```

Here is my attempt, but it's not working without trailing slash on a request like: http://www.example.com/de and is not redirecting http://www.example.com to a default language folder.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/\.]+)/?$ view-project.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I achieve this?

This is possible a duplicate and I apologize for that. I searched everywhere and read about 100 posts, but I did't found what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite.com/

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en|de)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(.+)$ $2&lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/\.]+)/?$ view-project.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

### Edit:

The above was before the detailed explanation: After the detailed explanation, I've come up with this solution which is very similar to the solution the author has come up with while I was not aware about the edit explaining the situation:

```
DirectorySlash Off # disables mod_dir slash redirect

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mysite.com/ # rewrites inside /mysite.com/

RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash # stops ignoring the directory redirects that redirect directories without slash, so by default: example.com/dir1 -> example.com/dir2 would be ignored. This is used because DirectorySlash is off

RewriteRule ^(en|de)\/projects\/(.+)$ view-project.php?lang=$1&path=$2 [QSA,L] # rule 4
RewriteRule ^(en|de)\/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L] # rule 1
RewriteRule ^$ en [R=302,L] # rule 2
RewriteRule ^(en|de)\/$ $1 [R=302,L] # rule 3
```

Answer (score 0):

after struggling a while and with the help of someone else, here is the .htaccess file that works for me:

```
RewriteBase /example.com/
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

RewriteRule ^$ de [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(de|en)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(de|en)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(de|en)/projects/(.+) view-project.php?lang=$1&path=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(de|en)/(.+) $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You have used 301 redirects. You have to be very careful not to make mistakes in these `RewriteRule`s. Since a 301 redirect in theory can be cached indefinitely.